# Obtain relevant data from dictionaries in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, vimeo

I'm trying to obtain information about my videos with certain tags on Vimeo. I've read through the API, but I can't find anything about requesting your videos which contain a certain tag. It only offers a tag search for public videos and a get all function for your own videos. So the only option it leaves me is to request all videos, then search through the dictionary for the relevant data.

However, Vimeo only allows you to request 100 videos at a time. Since there are more than 100 videos on my account I have to create a list of dictionaries to obtain all videos. This is the simplified list of dictionaries I'm talking about:

```
[{'data': [{'download': [{'created_time': '2017-11-30T15:01:44+00:00',
                      'expires': '2017-11-30T23:40:36+00:00',
                      'fps': 25,
                      'height': 360,
                      'link': 'https://player.vimeo.com/play/884123433?s=245200119_1512117636_a70a08b2710ec2c731c9d39729895c76&loc=external&context=Vimeo%5CController%5CApi%5CResources%5CUser%5CVideosController.&download=1&filename=05%2BF1%2BClassic%2BRaces%2B1983.%2BMonaco%2BHighlights164.mp4',
                      'md5': 'f87ad14ecf73f27bc4fd2ff537f9cf9b',
                      'quality': 'sd',
                      'size': 128905331,
                      'type': 'video/mp4',
                      'width': 520},
                     {'created_time': '2017-11-30T15:01:44+00:00',
                      'expires': '2017-11-30T23:40:36+00:00',
                      'fps': 50,
                      'height': 1080,
                      'link': 'https://player.vimeo.com/play/884123432?s=245200119_1512117636_ffaf6e2eb391b06cff5e534dfd026204&loc=external&context=Vimeo%5CController%5CApi%5CResources%5CUser%5CVideosController.&download=1&filename=05%2BF1%2BClassic%2BRaces%2B1983.%2BMonaco%2BHighlights169.mp4',
                      'md5': 'fe06de889adf38dceb92089427c4a0cc',
                      'quality': 'hd',
                      'size': 1072969191,
                      'type': 'video/mp4',
                      'width': 1560},
                     {'created_time': '2017-11-30T15:01:44+00:00',
                      'expires': '2017-11-30T23:40:36+00:00',
                      'fps': 50,
                      'height': 720,
                      'link': 'https://player.vimeo.com/play/884123428?s=245200119_1512117636_4f7665421693d392a0e7caabb331c075&loc=external&context=Vimeo%5CController%5CApi%5CResources%5CUser%5CVideosController.&download=1&filename=05%2BF1%2BClassic%2BRaces%2B1983.%2BMonaco%2BHighlights174.mp4',
                      'md5': '6b62e4aaa044f8802f6ba30c29047b69',
                      'quality': 'hd',
                      'size': 562614988,
                      'type': 'video/mp4',
                      'width': 1040},
                     {'created_time': '2017-11-30T15:01:44+00:00',
                      'expires': '2017-11-30T23:40:36+00:00',
                      'fps': 25,
                      'height': 540,
                      'link': 'https://player.vimeo.com/play/884123427?s=245200119_1512117636_a1718ab65d37637e0406c8ab099f8f50&loc=external&context=Vimeo%5CController%5CApi%5CResources%5CUser%5CVideosController.&download=1&filename=05%2BF1%2BClassic%2BRaces%2B1983.%2BMonaco%2BHighlights165.mp4',
                      'md5': '4d014ea00d0c8620869f5ad4c5b4e404',
                      'quality': 'sd',
                      'size': 364759333,
                      'type': 'video/mp4',
                      'width': 780},
                     {'created_time': '2017-11-30T15:01:44+00:00',
                      'expires': '2017-11-30T23:40:36+00:00',
                      'fps': 25,
                      'height': 1080,
                      'link': 'https://player.vimeo.com/play/884123417?s=245200119_1512117636_9c7ad015a30585c3cedb9429ffd0c9f2&loc=external&context=Vimeo%5CController%5CApi%5CResources%5CUser%5CVideosController.&download=1&filename=05%2BF1%2BClassic%2BRaces%2B1983.%2BMonaco%2BHighlights175.mp4',
                      'md5': 'd73682a6385154a83fe1653176bf17ab',
                      'quality': 'hd',
                      'size': 1071546729,
                      'type': 'video/mp4',
                      'width': 1560},
                     {'created_time': '2017-11-30T14:51:00+00:00',
                      'expires': '2017-11-30T23:40:36+00:00',
                      'fps': 50,
                      'height': 1080,
                      'link': 'https://player.vimeo.com/play/884114225?s=245200119_1512117636_034586db598d6b398ecf86fe7bb50fb7&loc=external&context=Vimeo%5CController%5CApi%5CResources%5CUser%5CVideosController.&download=1&filename=05%2BF1%2BClassic%2BRaces%2B1983.%2BMonaco%2BHighlightssource.webm',
                      'md5': '76bcb8c1cd19b7ffa4d59f7961bb3076',
                      'quality': 'source',
                      'size': 1429585788,
                      'type': 'source',
                      'width': 1560}],
        'tags': []},
    {'download': [{'created_time': '2017-11-25T18:13:28+00:00',
                      'expires': '2017-11-30T23:40:36+00:00',
                      'fps': 25,
                      'height': 540,
                      'link': 'https://player.vimeo.com/play/880414686?s=244460915_1512117636_e99e772d06f2be1f3e792e2eaf9649ab&loc=external&context=Vimeo%5CController%5CApi%5CResources%5CUser%5CVideosController.&download=1&filename=Formula1%2B2017%2BAbudhabi%2BQUalifying165.mp4',
                      'md5': '8e920c971257c4578ce9a23bcd532b2a',
                      'quality': 'sd',
                      'size': 1913433310,
                      'type': 'video/mp4',
                      'width': 960},
                     {'created_time': '2017-11-25T18:13:28+00:00',
                      'expires': '2017-11-30T23:40:36+00:00',
                      'fps': 50,
                      'height': 720,
                      'link': 'https://player.vimeo.com/play/880414685?s=244460915_1512117636_219ce4f61b0c8169d06951488b07a242&loc=external&context=Vimeo%5CController%5CApi%5CResources%5CUser%5CVideosController.&download=1&filename=Formula1%2B2017%2BAbudhabi%2BQUalifying174.mp4',
                      'md5': 'c4a58556df95ca0ee2283793b6f099cb',
                      'quality': 'hd',
                      'size': 3090734703,
                      'type': 'video/mp4',
                      'width': 1280},
                     {'created_time': '2017-11-25T18:13:28+00:00',
                      'expires': '2017-11-30T23:40:36+00:00',
                      'fps': 50,
                      'height': 1080,
                      'link': 'https://player.vimeo.com/play/880414684?s=244460915_1512117636_5ade2bfdffc7932dd0598bfff9f7ea58&loc=external&context=Vimeo%5CController%5CApi%5CResources%5CUser%5CVideosController.&download=1&filename=Formula1%2B2017%2BAbudhabi%2BQUalifying169.mp4',
                      'md5': '019552bae7ca1c71e5964c54dbdf8949',
                      'quality': 'hd',
                      'size': 5891693868,
                      'type': 'video/mp4',
                      'width': 1920},
                     {'created_time': '2017-11-25T18:13:28+00:00',
                      'expires': '2017-11-30T23:40:36+00:00',
                      'fps': 25,
                      'height': 360,
                      'link': 'https://player.vimeo.com/play/880414679?s=244460915_1512117636_4d1dc529cad10c2753b967987b3c6b06&loc=external&context=Vimeo%5CController%5CApi%5CResources%5CUser%5CVideosController.&download=1&filename=Formula1%2B2017%2BAbudhabi%2BQUalifying164.mp4',
                      'md5': '3daca0303792d0b7506b3247e7b6ee99',
                      'quality': 'sd',
                      'size': 719988849,
                      'type': 'video/mp4',
                      'width': 640},
                     {'created_time': '2017-11-25T18:13:28+00:00',
                      'expires': '2017-11-30T23:40:36+00:00',
                      'fps': 25,
                      'height': 1080,
                      'link': 'https://player.vimeo.com/play/880414677?s=244460915_1512117636_49c3975dd10c202fddd9e4e3418a150d&loc=external&context=Vimeo%5CController%5CApi%5CResources%5CUser%5CVideosController.&download=1&filename=Formula1%2B2017%2BAbudhabi%2BQUalifying175.mp4',
                      'md5': 'f1f38a8aa8612d9fa1331410a3a153f1',
                      'quality': 'hd',
                      'size': 5883105557,
                      'type': 'video/mp4',
                      'width': 1920},
                     {'created_time': '2017-11-25T18:11:34+00:00',
                      'expires': '2017-11-30T23:40:36+00:00',
                      'fps': 50,
                      'height': 1080,
                      'link': 'https://player.vimeo.com/play/880414164?s=244460915_1512117636_4a9ae40250b8d5f1ab803973cb4617cc&loc=external&context=Vimeo%5CController%5CApi%5CResources%5CUser%5CVideosController.&download=1&filename=Formula1%2B2017%2BAbudhabi%2BQUalifyingsource.',
                      'md5': '21425a206698038bc9e8114698a187e9',
                      'quality': 'source',
                      'size': 7026953324,
                      'type': 'source',
                      'width': 1920}],
        'tags': [{'canonical': 'foo',
                  'metadata': {'connections': {'videos': {'options': ['GET'],
                                                          'total': 109,
                                                          'uri': '/tags/foo/videos'}}},
                  'name': 'Foo',
                  'resource_key': '3b4ab793385a07c695ef0081210c8fd586e2d890',
                  'tag': 'Foo',
                  'uri': '/tags/foo'},
                 {'canonical': '2017',
                  'metadata': {'connections': {'videos': {'options': ['GET'],
                                                          'total': 158765,
                                                          'uri': '/tags/2017/videos'}}},
                  'name': '2017',
                  'resource_key': 'a5c9f20cc79135f49b431c20b779e7b93bd26415',
                  'tag': '2017',
                  'uri': '/tags/2017'}]}]
},"second_dict"]
```

What I want: I want to find all videos which contain the tag `Foo`, then get the download link from `'type': 'source'`. So I want to end up with `["data"]["download"]["link"]` where `'type':'source'`.

I tried writing a bit of code which checks for tags and then creates a list with only the videos containing the 'Foo' tag:

```
videosFiltered = []
for entry in videos:
    for subentry in entry["data"]:
        if subentry["tags"] and subentry["tags"][0]["name"] == "Foo":
            videosFiltered.append()
```

But as you can see I'm failing miserably, since I'm just writing terrifying nests of for loops and if loops. I'm pretty sure I will eventually get what I want, but I was hoping you could help me find a more elegant solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/tags/:word/videos` is the resource you're looking for. Hitting `/tags/foo/videos` should return a paginated list of videos that have the "foo" tag.

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/tags#GET/tags/{word}/videos

Comment: This only returns public videos though? I'm trying to find my own videos containing tags, so I tried:

`videosTotal = v.get('https://api.vimeo.com/me/tags/:word/videos').json()`, where `v` is the authentication part. 

But that doesn't work. Solving this at the API request level would be the best solution.

Comment: Ah damn, you're right, my bad, `/tags/:word/videos` is for public videos, not your own. We definitely don't have an endpoint for that right now, so your solution isn't definitely ideal but is necessary. Sorry :(

Comment: Would you still be able to help a little? I want to get the right data, but I don't want to make a mess of nested loops. If you only know a better way to index dictionaries in lists-like structures, that would already be a big help.

Comment: This code against the `/tags/:word/videos` resource, but the same filtering code should apply to you on `/me/videos`. 

https://gist.github.com/erunion/0877e8186c4b564f6140a682831db200